# Can't start the chronometer or not working properly

Tags: android, timer, chronometer

When I start the chronometer from another class with the `start()` function. It doesn't seem to be starting. It always gives me the beginning value `"00:00"` and nothing more.

```
 public class Kronometre {
    Context context;
    long countUp;
    Chronometer stopWatch;
    String asText = "00.00";

    public Kronometre(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        stopWatch = new Chronometer(context);
    }

    public void start() {
        stopWatch.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
                countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0.getBase()) / 1000;
                asText = (countUp / 60) + "." + (countUp % 60);
            }
        });
        stopWatch.start();
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return asText;
    }
}
```

Comment: add `Chronometer` in `setContentView()` or add `Chronometer` to a activity's visible parent layout..

Comment: I really didn't understand man. What is activity's visible parent layout? Could you be more explanatory.

Comment: Suppose you have `setContentView(myLinearLay);` then you have to add `myLinearLay.add(stopWatch )` before setcontentView where `stopWatch` is your chronometer object

Comment: Sorry man still dont get it. I am using a surfaceView and it doesn't have an add() function.